# How can I make an assembly for .net core 3.1 and .netstandard2.0?

Tags: .net-core, assemblies, .net-standard-2.0

Can anyone please tell me what's the correct approach? This is my project file

```
  <PropertyGroup> 
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" Version="4.7.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

and this is parts of the nuspec file

```
   <dependencies>
      <group targetFramework=".NETStandard2.1">
        <dependency id="Microsoft.CSharp" version="4.7.0" />
      </group>
      <group targetFramework=".NetCore,Version=3.1">
        <dependency id="Microsoft.CSharp" version="4.7.0" />
      </group>
    </dependencies>
    <packageTypes>
      <packageType name="Dependency" />
    </packageTypes>  
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="bin\$configuration$\**\*.*" exclude="**\*.pdb" target=".\lib"/>
  </files>
```

When building the assembly using Cake we specify `Win-x64` as the runtime. Is this correct?

The file/folder structure in the generated nupkg is

```
\lib
   \netcoreapp3.1
      \any
      \win
      \win-x64
   \netstandard2.0
      \win10-x64
```

Tools: VS2019, NuGet v5.4.0

Then when I try to install it in a .net core 3.1 project I get the dreaded:

```
Error   NU1202  Package JDM.Common.Json 0.2.2 is not compatible with netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1). Package JDM.Common.Json 0.2.2 does not support any target frameworks. ...
```

I must admit that not being able to get this working is driving me crazy.

TIA

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to create a nuspec file for this. You can use the plural `TargetFrameworks` and specify multiple target frameworks:

```
  <PropertyGroup> 
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.1;netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Then you can create the .nupk file using `dotnet pack`

Comment: Sweet. How do I deal with the dependency on `Microsoft.CSharp Version="4.7.0"`. Just as before?

Comment: Also, we use TeamCity as our build/intergation server and we call nuget from there and let TC place the nupkg file(s) in its local nuget repository. Is that possible with `dotnet pack`directly?

Comment: TeamCity has a .NET CLI task as well, but i'm not a TC user https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/net-cli-dotnet.html?_ga=2.84568857.1481958873.1585087326-2007815823.1585087326